# Removing an object from a dictionary in lua

Tags: dictionary, lua, aerospike

I am using aerospike for storage and its UDF's in Lua. While executing the udf's through both NodeJS and Python- I need to delete a key-value pair from the dictionary being passed as a parameter.

Below is the code snippets:

```
function deleteProduct(rec, prod_id, isodate)
    map.remove(rec, prod_id)
    aerospike:update(rec)
    return 0
end
```

And the rec structure is:

```
{
    meta.num_prod: 4
    s.10000006: {
      prod_id: "10000006"
      qty: "4"
 }
```

I do understand that pythonic dictionary is not same as Lua maps- but I am  stuck with this. I get the error message as:

```
/opt/aerospike/usr/udf/lua/update.lua:14: bad argument #1 to \'remove\' (Map expected, got userdata)
```

The rec is the aerospike record being invoked in the below manner:

```
                var udf = { module:'update', funcname: 'deleteProductFromCart', args: [prod_key, isoDate]}
            sails.aerospike.execute(cart_key, udf, function(err, result) {
                if(err.code!=status.AEROSPIKE_OK){
                    console.log(err)
                    defer.resolve(false)
                }
                else{
                    defer.resolve(true)
                }
            });
```

Comment: Where does `rec`'s value come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below works just fine!

```
 map[key] = nil
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the provided error message, you should call it this way (through colon):

```
map:remove(rec, prod_id)
```

I am sure you know what is the difference.

Comment: Thanks a tonne! Apparently I did not know the difference! But thanks!